# how can I add to columns in R

Tags: r

I cannot seem to add two columns in R.

when I try

```
dat$V1 + dat$V2
```

I get

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(dat$V1, dat$V2) : + not meaningful for factors
```

lots of other questions suggest to do as I have done, however as you can see this does not work for me. what is the problem?

Comment: You should investigate why the columns are factors and not numerics as you expect. Most probably, this happend during data import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to convert your factor columns to numeric: If `V1` and `V2` are 1st two columns.

```
dat[,1:2] <- lapply(dat[,1:2], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

dat$V1 +dat$V2
```

For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(V1= factor(1:5), V2= factor(6:10))
dat$V1+dat$V2
#[1] NA NA NA NA NA
#Warning message:
#In Ops.factor(dat$V1, dat$V2) : + not meaningful for factors

dat[,1:2] <- lapply(dat[,1:2], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

dat$V1 +dat$V2
#[1]  7  9 11 13 15
```